# My Application is being crashed and getting the java.lang.NullPointerException in CustomAdapter

Tags: android

I have an application with various tabs (on a tabhost), each tab is an activity that extends activity, and haves some textfields and things on it.On my first tab i am using it for showing the listview which is using customadapter and this list is getting data from server and data is updating after each 3 seconds in list.App is working fine but sometime it is being crashed and showing java.lang.NullPointerException in CustomAdapter in some point.

my code is mention below my class is like this

```
public  class BaseActivity extends Activity  {

private ListView list;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

private final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1010;
private Timer timer = new Timer();
private  String response;
protected Dialog m_ProgressDialog;
String[] operatorList,operatorDetail,operatordetail,tempoperatordata;
String[] noofvisitors,opt;
private static final String DEB_TAG = "Error Message";
public static ArrayList<String> SessionText,IPText,DurationText;
private ArrayList<String> StatusText,NoOfVisit,ButtonText;
private int sizeoflist;
private String IP;
Context context;
public static String from,sessionid,id,text,iptext,status;
private int position,noofchat;
private boolean IsSoundEnable,IsChatOnly;
private Button logout;
private CustomAdapter adapter;
NotificationManager notificationManager;



final HashMap<String, String> postParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
private String url;

private Handler handler; 
private Runnable updater; 




    private void TimerMethod()
    {
        //This method is called directly by the timer
        //and runs in the same thread as the timer.

        //We call the method that will work with the UI
        //through the runOnUiThread method.
        this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);

    } 

    private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

        //This method runs in the same thread as the UI.               

        //Do something to the UI thread here
            getVisitorDetailFromServer();




           try {
              Log.i("UPDATE", "Handler called");
             // searchAdapter = getFeed(URL);

              //handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);

           } catch(Exception e) {
              Log.e("UPDATE ERROR", e.getMessage());
           }



        }
    };





@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.visitor);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list01);

    logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogout);

    // list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

     //list.clearChoices();





    //-----------------Making the object of arrayList----------------

    SessionText = new ArrayList<String>();
    IPText = new ArrayList<String>();
    DurationText = new ArrayList<String>();
    StatusText = new ArrayList<String>();
    NoOfVisit = new ArrayList<String>();
    ButtonText = new ArrayList<String>();

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        IsSoundEnable = Controls.IsSoundEnable;
        IsChatOnly = Controls.IsChatOnly;
        IsSoundEnable = extras.getBoolean("IsSoundOnly", Controls.IsSoundEnable);
        IsChatOnly= extras.getBoolean("IsCOnlyhat", Controls.IsChatOnly);
        extras.getString("From");
        position=extras.getInt("Position");


    }



}



@Override
protected void onStart() {

    super.onStart();

    //------------Getting the visitor detail-------------------------


     //getVisitorDetailFromServer();
       adapter = new CustomAdapter(BaseActivity.this);
       timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
           public void run() {
               TimerMethod();
           }

       }, 0, 6000); 



    /*handler = new Handler();
     updater = new Runnable() {

     public void run() {

       /*
        * Update the list 
        */

     /*    getVisitorDetailFromServer();




       try {
          Log.i("UPDATE", "Handler called");
         // searchAdapter = getFeed(URL);

          handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);

       } catch(Exception e) {
          Log.e("UPDATE ERROR", e.getMessage());
       }

      }

     };

        updater.run();*/








    //---------------When user click on logout button-----------------------------------


        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            logoutFromServer();


        }



    });


}


//----------------------------Getting the detail from server of monitoring window-------------------------


private void getVisitorDetailFromServer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub




        url = "http://sa.live2support.com/cpn/wz1-allonlineu.php?";
        postParameters.put("adminid",Main.loginId.getText().toString());
        postParameters.put("sid",Main.siteId.getText().toString());
        postParameters.put("nvar","Y");
        postParameters.put("conly", "N");


    Runnable searchThread = new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {

                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost1(url,postParameters);

                Log.i(DEB_TAG, "Requesting to server"+response);
                //CustomHttpClient.getResponseInString(response );

                System.out.println("Output of httpResponse:"+response);

                String result = response;
                result = response;

                String delimiter1 = "<ln>";
                String delimiter = "<fld>";

                operatorDetail = result.split(delimiter1);
                for(int i=0;i<operatorDetail.length;i++){

                    operatorList = operatorDetail[i].split(delimiter);
                    SessionText.add(operatorList[0]);
                    IPText.add(operatorList[1]);
                    DurationText.add(operatorList[4]);
                    StatusText.add(operatorList[3]);
                    NoOfVisit.add(operatorList[2]);
                    ButtonText.add(operatorList[6]);


                    //System.out.println("value of iptext is"+IPText.get(i));




                }

                operatorDetail=null;
                operatorList=null;
                SessionText = null;
                IPText =null;
                DurationText=null;
                StatusText=null;
                NoOfVisit=null;
                ButtonText=null;




                operatorDetail = result.split(delimiter1);

                SessionText = new ArrayList<String>();
                IPText = new ArrayList<String>();
                DurationText = new ArrayList<String>();
                StatusText = new ArrayList<String>();
                NoOfVisit = new ArrayList<String>();
                ButtonText = new ArrayList<String>();




                //--------Getting the size of the list---------------------

                sizeoflist = operatorDetail.length;




            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(response!=null){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        playsound3();
                        noofchat =0;

                        list.setAdapter(adapter);
                        list.getDrawingCache(false);
                        list.invalidateViews();
                        list.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        list.requestFocus(0);
                        list.setSelected(false);
                        // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                       // list.getAdapter().notifyAll();
                        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {

                                String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();


                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        });

                        if(IsChatOnly==false){
                            TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {

                                    //triggerNotification();
                                    //playsound();

                                }
                            };
                            timer.schedule(timerTask, 3000);
                        }
                        else{

                            playsound();
                        }



                    }


                });
            }

            else {

                ShowAlert();
            }


        }
    };

    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, searchThread, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();




}
```

the adapter class that i am using for the class is like this

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;




    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();



    }



    public int getCount() {
        return sizeoflist;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row1, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.IP = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ip);
            holder.duration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
            holder.status =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
            holder.noOfVisit = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.NoOfvisit);
            holder.invite =(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnjoin);
            holder.deny = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btndeny);
            //holder.accept = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnaccept);


            holder.deny.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            holder.invite.setId(position);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }


        String result = response;

        String delimiter = "<fld>";
        String delimiter1 = "<ln>";
        String delimiter2 = "<blk>";
        String delimiter3 = "<fld><fld><blk>";
        operatorDetail = result.split(delimiter1);
        String[] operatorlist = result.split(delimiter3);
        noofvisitors = operatorlist[1].split(delimiter2);

        //System.out.println("no of visitor================"+noofvisitors[0]);

        for(int i=0;i<operatorDetail.length;i++){


            operatorList = operatorDetail[i].split(delimiter);

            operatorlist = result.split(delimiter2);


            SessionText.add(operatorList[0]);
            IPText.add(operatorList[1]);
            DurationText.add(operatorList[4]);
            StatusText.add(operatorList[3]);
            NoOfVisit.add(operatorList[2]);
            ButtonText.add(operatorList[6]);



            //if(StatusText.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("chat request")){
                //holder.deny.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //holder.invite.setText("Accept");
                //holder.accept.setText("Accept");
                /*holder.accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        holder.invite.setText("Join");
                        holder.deny.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        //chatRequest(IPText.get(position), SessionText.get(position));
                    }
                });*/

            //}
            //else{
            //  holder.invite.setText("Invite");
                holder.deny.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //  //holder.accept.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //}



            holder.invite.setText("Invite");
            holder.deny.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


            if(holder.invite.getText().equals("Join")){

                holder.invite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        chatRequest(iptext,sessionid);
                    }
                });
            }


            holder.IP.setText(IPText.get(position));
            holder.duration.setText(DurationText.get(position));
            holder.status.setText(StatusText.get(position));
            holder.noOfVisit.setText(NoOfVisit.get(position));


            //---------------------When user click on invite Button---------------------


            holder.invite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    callToServer(SessionText.get(position));
                }
            });



            //-----------------------------When user click on deny button------------------------

            holder.deny.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    refuseToServer(sessionid);
                    holder.deny.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }




            });



        }



        System.out.println("no of visitor================"+noofvisitors[0]);




        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(BaseActivity.this,VisitorDetail.class);
                i.putExtra("ID", id);
                i.putExtra("Position",position);
                i.putExtra("From", from);
                i.putExtra("SessionText", SessionText.get(position));
                i.putExtra("IPTEXT",IPText.get(position));
                startActivity(i);
            }});
        //startService();
        return convertView;
    }


    class ViewHolder {
        TextView IP;
        TextView duration;
        Button deny;
        TextView status;
        TextView noOfVisit;
        Button invite;
        Button accept;
    }
}
```

the logcat like this

```
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 0
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at com.live2support.BaseActivity$CustomAdapter.getView(BaseActivity.java:719)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:563)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:378)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:578)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:362)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-23 14:05:42.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

what i am doing wrong?I am unable to understand.................
Can anyone help me?

or logcat sometime like this

02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at com.live2support.BaseActivity$CustomAdapter.getView(BaseActivity.java:670)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:563)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:378)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:578)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:362)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-23 15:01:01.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: why my app being crashed.some field related to this activity is also using in other actives of tab.

Comment: can anyone tell me what i use exactly i am unable to understand why app is being crashed.

Comment: can you attach the logcat error? It would also help me if you can highlight the line that is actually causing the bug. The NPE should give you a line number. I don't want the line number since all I have are code blocks, lol.

Comment: Please point out the exact line of code that is generating the NPE.

Comment: I'm also surprised that your called to startActivity() in your convertView's onClickListener isn't giving you problems. Which leads me to believe that all of this code is in one big file since you need something that extends context, which certainly didn't help your formatting at all.

Comment: okay i am adding the logcat detail......

Comment: i am getting exception at the point   02-23 15:51:11.208: E/AndroidRuntime(3742):  at com.live2support.BaseActivity$CustomAdapter.getView(BaseActivity.java:660)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems one of your arraylist is having data less then list size,  See which arraylist object on the line numbetr 719, you are trying to access, and check why this arraylist is not equal to list size.

Comment: I am getting the exception at  this line                               SessionText.add(operatorList[0]);